# Reverse relation of role model

Tags: meaning

If A is a role model to B.

B is what to A?

I assume there is something more focused than `fan` or `follower`.

Comment: Padowan! in the Star Wars universe anyway.

Comment: Or "grasshopper" from Kung Fu...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **Acolyte** *noun*
>
> follower, fan, supporter, pupil, convert, believer, admirer, backer, partisan, disciple, devotee, worshipper, apostle, cohort (chiefly U.S.), fan club (informal), adherent, henchman, habitué, votary To his acolytes, he is known simply as 'The Boss'.
>
> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acolyte)
>
> **Disciple**
>
> Etymology
>
> From Old English discipul, from Latin discipulus (“a pupil, learner”), from discere (“to learn”); akin to docere (“to teach”). Later influenced or superceded in Middle English by Old French deciple.
>
> **disciple** *noun* (plural *disciples*):
>
> **1**.A person who learns from another, especially one who then teaches others.
>
> **2**.An active follower or adherent of someone, or some philosophy etc

from the Wikitionary [**link**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disciple)

> **Student** *noun* (figuratively)
>
> **2**: A person seriously devoted to some subject, whether academic or not. He is a student of life.
>
> The Wiktionary [**link**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/student)
>
> **Protégé** *noun* (plural proteges)
>
> **1**. A person guided and protected by a more prominent person. His status as a protege of the great artist had many benefits, but was ultimately a burden.
>
> The Wiktionary [**link**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protege)

**Shout-out! to JR**

Comment: +1 disciple - evocative of a follower or a fan of someone.

Comment: @L consider adding *protege* to your fine answer.

Comment: `Disciple` is probably closest to what I was looking for. Thanks for all the information.

Answer (score 8):

You could call them an *[aspirant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspirant)*

> a person who tries to become something : a person who aspires to do or to be something

*Merriam-Webster*

Comment: Can you give an in-context example?

Comment: @JNF *She was the epitome of fashion sense; I, a mere aspirant.*

Comment: Nothing to do with breathing or sweating!

Comment: @WS2 It will take a good deal of both for me to catch up!

Comment: Well, "journey of a thousand miles ..." and now you're one step closer, but with a paltry 3,221 vs 47.4k, it's I whose the aspirant to your epitome. +1, bib.

Comment: Seems to be missing the relation. It stands alone.

Comment: @LittleEva But your answers were so much further along the path than mine. That's why +1ed it. And most others agree.

Answer (score 1):

B is the protégé of A.

> **protégé**
>
> One who is protected or trained or whose career is furthered by a
>   person of experience, prominence, or influence