# What is the best noun to describe people who are influenced by something in both good and bad ways unwillingly?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is influenced by some external factors unwillingly?

Sample sentence:

> Technologies have become ubiquitous—affecting every perspective of our daily lives.

How would you call *the people who are affected by technologies without voluntarily choosing so*?

Here are some related questions:

- [Word for people easily influenced by propaganda](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/word-for-people-easily-influenced-by-propaganda)
- [What do you call someone who is easily influenced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326907/what-do-you-call-someone-who-is-easily-influenced)
- [What is the best antonym for "influencer"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571543/what-is-the-best-antonym-for-influencer)
- [Reverse relation of role model](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227996/reverse-relation-of-role-model)

Some recommended words are "follower", "acolyte", "credulous". These words refer to people who are either willingly choose to be influenced, or easy to accept influences. I am looking for words that describe people who are affected without making a choice and not necessarily "gullible" (i.e., students who are affected by college admission algorithms).

---

**Edit**

Some other related questions:

- [Is there one word for "being deceived into complying"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442414/is-there-one-word-for-being-deceived-into-complying/442415#442415)

Here, the recommended words "beguiled" and "tricked" imply a strong negative sentiment to the "influencer". I am looking for a more neutral word. For example, technologies have both good and bad influences on people. People are not necessarily tricked by technologies, but just being affected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right word as I heard so many times can be **manipulate** as you can see in [LongMan](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/manipulate)

> manipulate (v) to make someone think and behave exactly as you want them to, by skillfully deceiving or influencing them

Example:

> You have the constant feeling you are being manipulated.

[edited]
You can see more examples [here](https://ludwig.guru/s/manipulate)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just clarified my question a little bit. I think "manipulate" has a negative sentiment. In the example, technologies influence people in both good and bad ways, so it doesn't really manipulate people.

Comment: I don't think it has a negative meaning, maybe in the example I gave you it is negative but in IMHO the negative word is **brainwash** rather than manipulate.

Comment: For me *manipulate* has a negative tone. *Handle* or *manage* are similar in meaning but more neutral in tone. The words do not describe those who are managed though.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What do you call someone who is influenced by some external factors unwillingly?
> 2. <s>How</s> **What** would you call the people who are affected by technologies without voluntarily choosing so?
> 3. I am looking for words that describe people who are affected without making a choice and not necessarily "gullible".

You have described three distinct types of people.

1. **an unwilling victim/volunteer.** Once you have established a context, you may use the substantivised adjective "the unwilling": They know it is happening but cannot avoid it - they continue their objections.
2. **an unwitting victim/volunteer.** Once you have established a context, you  may use the substantivised adjective "the unwitting": They do not know it is happening but comply.
3. **a reluctant volunteer.** Once you have established a context, you  may use the substantivised adjective "the reluctant": They know it is happening but cannot avoid it - they accept the situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Impressionable**

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/impressionable)

> Someone who is impressionable is easily influenced. An impressionable person can be greatly changed by his or her experiences — not always in a good way.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/impressionable)

> Someone who is impressionable, usually a young person, is not very critical and is therefore easy to influence.